# Getting number of pattern matches in VTE search

Tags: linux, gtk3, gnome, vala, vte

I'm developing a GTK+ 3.0 application that uses VTE widget, how can I get the number of occurrences for the search regex or at least get the current text in terminal and process that?

I'm using VTE 2.91 and Vala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Vte.Terminal.get_text()`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=vte-2.91/Vte.Terminal.get_text) will get you the currently *visible* text in the terminal for processing. I'm not sure that that includes text that's scrolled off the screen.

You could try `Vte.Terminal.select_all()` followed by `Vte.Terminal.copy_clipboard()`, then get the copied text off the clipboard, but I'm not sure that will work.

Comment: I confirm that the second method _does_ get all text, including the scrollback buffer.